# JSP and OSGi: bundling css and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, osgi

Do some implemented OSGi frameworks allow me to bundle css styles and javascript as well?

Or i have to use other approaches to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a WAB (Web Application Bundle), it's a war with OSGi manifest which needs a Web-ContextPath attribute, this doesn't necessarily be a war it may also be a jar with a war like structure. 
Might want to take a look at the Pax Web Framework (or [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) wich uses it). 
The [Pax Web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) framework provides all that is needed to deploy Servlets/JSPs resources etc. also in a OSGi manner. Yes also as Services via a Whiteboard approach. Another point is Servlet 3 and CDI, all of this is also supported by Pax Web (for CDI you'll also need Pax CDI)
Best take a look at the various [samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples) and the [integration tests](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty).

Answer (score 1):

You can have any resource in a jar. This is not the question of OSGi framework, but the question of the technology you would like to use. How will it find the resource in your jar.

E.g.: If you create a WAB, that behaves similar to a WAR.

Although WABs can be used with several OSGi based web server, I personally do not like them as they are monoholitic. There are alternatives to provide resources:

https://github.com/bndtools/aQute/tree/master/aQute.webserver

An implementation by Peter Kriens that allows us to download any files that are placed into the /static/ folder of any bundle. The Servlet is registered on the /static/ path so if you have a file in your bundle at /static/css/mystyle.css, you can access it via http://foo.com/static/css/mystyle.css

https://github.com/everit-org/webresource

Similar solution but this is based on bundle capabilities. The first release is expected in the end of October 2014, but the important logic is already implemented. This library needs OSGi 6.0 and Java 8 since the latest commit that might be a limitation for a while.

JSPs are other question. If you use a WAB and an embedded Servlet container with JSP support, they should work. You can also register the JSP servlet manually into your OSGi container based on the technology you use (e.g.: with whiteboard pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Amdatu has support for this in the [Web Resources component](http://amdatu.org/components/web.html). You simply add your static resources to the bundle using the -Include-Resource bnd header and add a few manifest headers to serve the files directly.

An example of this could be the following. This example can be found in the [Amdatu Chat example](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/amdatu-examples-chat/src/735f767e078311b81fac332de25648404104df56/org.amdatu.chat.ui/bnd.bnd?at=master).

```
Include-Resource: \
app=dist/app
X-Web-Resource-Default-Page: index.html
X-Web-Resource-Version: 1.1
X-Web-Resource: /chat;app
```